# How to add lazy loading to react-table with static JSON as data?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-table, react-table-v7

Using the react-table v7 library, I'm making a table. The data I'm supplying in this table is prefetched and saved as JSON. This JSON file has the formatting that react-table requires.

But My data is very vast and has numerous deep hierarchies. Expanded option tables are what I'm making.
When I feed this data into a react-table, the rendering takes too long, which slows down the application's overall speed.

I want to add lazy loading so that when the user clicks on expand option, the children of that row should get added dynamically from my data.
I am referring to this  [example](https://medium.com/tenjin-engineering/lazy-loading-expandable-rows-with-react-table-cd2fc86b0630)Lazy loading in this example the children data is being fetched on click is randomly created there is no hierarchy to maintain.
In My case data is already there I want to fetch children of that particular row when the user clicks on expand row button.

In summary, how can I get the children's row when the user clicks on the parent row?

I am attaching a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-paper-85h1e2) to code sandbox where I created react table with static data.

Let me know if i am missing anything or you need more details. Thank you

I attempted to implement lazy loading using the aforementioned example, but the data for the lazy loaded row in that example was generated at random, whereas in my situation I wanted to fetch data for the row whose parent row's expand button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useEffect` hook to load the data. Try this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Create a state variable to store the data, and a state variable to store the current page of data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [pageData, setPageData] = useState([]);
```

Use the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Load the first page of data
  const loadData = async () => {
    // Fetch the data from the JSON file
    const response = await fetch('data.json');
    const jsonData = await response.json();

    // Set the data to the state variable
    setData(jsonData);

    // Set the first page of data to the pageData state variable
    setPageData(jsonData.slice(0, 10));
  };
  loadData();
}, []);
```

Then pass in the `pageData` state variable as the data prop

```
const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({
  data: pageData,
  // ... other table configuration options
});
```

Add a button to load the next page of data

```
const handleLoadNextPage = () => {
  // Calculate the next page of data
  const nextPageData = data.slice(pageData.length, pageData.length + 10);

  // Update the pageData state variable with the next page of data
  setPageData([...pageData, ...nextPageData]);
};
```

And at last, render the table and the button in the component, could look like this:

```
return (
  <>
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onClick={handleLoadNextPage}>Load Next Page</button>
  </>
);
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: To get the children's row use the `useExpanded` hook from react-table. `onClick={() => toggleExpanded(row.id)}`

Comment: Thanks for the response Agan I tried solution you mentioned but it did not work for me. I ended up shifting to the version 8 of react table which solves my slow loading problem